# Take speech from user and start specific service

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

Here is what I am trying to do, I have specified a trigger word now what I want my application to do is to listen form user, convert that input into a string, then compare that string with my trigger word string and if they match then my application should take us to the messaging service I donot know how to convert arraylist to a string pleas guide me to carry further.
Thank you in advance
 Here is my code:

```
 package com.example.ahsan.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by ahsan on 5/21/2016.
 */

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;
    String trigger="open messaging";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* showing google speech input dialog*/
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);

        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }


    }
    /* Receiving speech Input */

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just mean how you get a String from an array of Strings?

Comment: I want to get the recorded speech in a string so that i can compare it with my initialized trigger word string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you mean? `s` below is all of the Strings in the Array:

```
    for(String s : text){
        if(s.matches(trigger){
        // We have a match!
          break;
        }
     }
```

Comment: can I ask for further help here?

Comment: @ahsanarif unless it's short and related, you probably need to post another question?

Comment: I have posted a question related to this I am having trouble in writing the accessibility class. Here is the link to my question thank you for your help really appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442316/how-should-i-place-my-text-to-speech-code-in-accessibility-service